# Why do we have int type in Java?

Tags: java

Why do we have int type in Java? Couldn't the only numeric type be double (and maybe float)? You can keep any integer number in a variable of type double.

Comment: if you had to enter the number of children you plan to have, do you think you need decimals there, or will a natural number (no decimals) suffice ? Next to this, there are performance reasons.

Comment: Floats and doubles also have a lot of precision problems that integers do not have.

Comment: Why even use Java? Go straight to machine code.

Comment: In addition to Stultuske's comment, floating point arithmetics are a bit of a nightmare

Comment: And the precision problems mentioned means that you can't use them as indexes. The reasons really are endless. You should dig into some computer history.

Comment: Some of the bits in floating point numbers are used for an exponent, so the range of integer values of a float (which is 32 bits) is smaller than the range of an int (32 bits). For instance, [this link](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/flintmax.html) says that the largest consecutive integer in IEEE single precision is 16777216 (2^24), which is far smaller than the largest integer in an equivalent integer type,  2147483647 (2^31 - 1)

Comment: @Stultuske realy good example

Comment: *"You can keep any integer number in a variable of type double."*--try to compare `(double)5_000_000_000_000L` and `(double)4_999_999_999_999L` to see why you're wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For performance reasons and memory saving. Plus , the fact that the numbers are precise with no decimal values is very handy for a lot of cases.

Comment: no, not for this. Integers and floating-point numbers are different by nature.

Comment: But if I keep a number with no decimal digits in a double value, all calculations on such variable will be no less precise than if that variable is double, I guess?

Comment: @user983447 `double` uses 52 bits for mantissa, but `long` uses all 64 bits for integer number. While your numbers are not so large, calculations (not all calculations) will be accurate. When they become larger, you'll get wrong results. For example, `(double)5_000_000_000_000_000_000L == ((double)5_000_000_000_000_000_000L + 1)` will return `true`